Without System Restore, after clicking 'Deleted Files', how can I recover a deleted profile?
I followed this moderator's post on Support Mozilla.

My hard drive lacks space for System Restore, which I forgot to turn on. After I mistakably clicked 'Delete files' 2 hours ago, Recuva recovered these 53 files, too little for a Firefox User Profile ?

Wise Data Recovery recovered 13 files, 108.37 KB, but again too little for a Firefox User Profile?


Are you running from an SSD?

Based on the information you provided, recovery of your data, will not be possible

Your list of recovered files omits those essential for the profile, e.g., extensions.json, addons.json, prefs.js, permissions.sqlite, logins.json, etc. If you do not make disk images, you'll have to create the profile anew.

Does this answer your question? How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?

It's one thing to find the files, and quite another thing for them to a) contain the data they need to have, and b) be in the order/folder structure the application expects them to be in. This is a problem backups solve, but they only solve it if you're already backing things up. Alternatively, Firefox has a sync feature that takes care of this too.
